# Which Data types are correct for storing numeric year input and numeric month in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am learning oracle 11g. I need to create columns to store Year and Month in the following sample format:

- Year: 2015
- Month: 6

I saw Date Time data type which takes whole date only .Also Number type may allow invalid year and month. But I want them in the given form while avoiding invalid month and  year. Please tell me how to fix it.thanks

Updates: is this okay for such inputs?

```
CREATE TABLE FOOBAR (YYYY DATE, MM DATE);
```

Comment: Use the `datetime` data type - job done

Comment: @Ed Heal  thanks.are you sure. i sawthat ,The datetime format model for the string '11-Nov-1999' is 'DD-Mon-YYYY'

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: i added the post.please reply.thanks @Ed Heal

Comment: DATETIME only stores valid dates - So what is the question?

Comment: @Ed Heal ,I want store year input and month input individually in the database, instead of togather (DD-MM-YYYY) thanks

Comment: Why? If you want a number within a certain range then use a trigger/constraint

Comment: @EdHeal - why would you use a trigger?  This seems like it calls for a constraint?

Comment: @APC - There are many ways to break an egg. It is very early in the morning here and that was the thing that was on the top of my head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to store dates in `DATE` columns.  Oracle has some pretty neat date functions, and you'll find it easy to work with storing the first of the month in a single `DATE` column.  Otherwise you'll find yourself constantly extracting elements from other dates or cluttering your code with `TO_CHAR()` and `TO_DATE()` calls. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions002.htm#SQLRF51179).

However, if you have a rigid requirement, you can use strong typing and check constraints to avoid invalid months:

```
CREATE TABLE FOOBAR (
      YYYY number(4,0) not null
      , MM number(2,0) not null
      , constraint foobar_yyyy_ck check (yyyy != 0)
      , constraint foobar_mm_ck check (mm between 1 and 12)
      );
```

This won't do what you want because it will default the missing elements:

```
CREATE TABLE FOOBAR (YYYY DATE, MM DATE);
```

We can't store just a year or just a month in `DATE` columns.

Comment: You can also make a constraint on DATE: `CHECK( TRUNC(COLUMN_NAME, 'IW') = COLUMN_NAME)) `

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - mmmm, yes we can, but to what end?

Comment: To ensure that any date is 1st. Day of months 00:00:00 - that's the values which are intended to be inserted only and you cannot have any ambiguous data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - um, that would be `trunc(column_name, 'MM')`.  IW is the mask for week, not month.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DATE` data type..

and when perform insert operation onto your db.. use

`TO_DATE ('November 13, 1992', 'MONTH DD, YYYY')`

For input and output of dates, the standard Oracle date format is `DD-MON-YY`, as follows:

`'13-NOV-92'`

perform insert operation/query like this:

`INSERT INTO table_name (name, created_at) VALUES 
    ('ANDY', TO_DATE ('November 13, 1992', 'MONTH DD, YYYY'));`

Here is link to the guide as well:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847

If you want to store month and year separately in the db you may use `NUMBER` & `NUMBER(n)`
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289

Hope this helps..